# ILogger log.LogInformation() output not visible in log stream or log files when azure function is deployed

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a durable azure function with ILogger log.LogInformation commands to help troubleshoot it while under development.

when running it on my machine the LogInformation commands print to the console, but when deployed, only a small number of them are output to the log stream.

There can be two of these LogInformation commands right beside eachother, but only one of them will output a message to the log stream.

Have i forgotten to enable something to ensure all these messages get output to the log stream?

Comment: could you please show us the code of that log related only and the output so that we can reproduce from our end and try to resolve the problem!

Comment: not really. there are a number of methods. they all call "loginformation" at various points to indicate that the process reached that point.

I cant post the functions though.

Comment: Are you using ILogger in all places, or a mix of `ILogger` and `ILogger<T>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure Functions runtime samples Application Insights telemetry by default to ***avoid emitting data*** too frequently. When a large number of lifecycle events occur in a short period of time, tracking information may be lost.

The durable function inputs and outputs of Orchestrator, Activity, and entity functions are not logged by default. Because it may increase the cost of Application Insights.

If you want to log the full input and output payloads in a **Durable function** we have to set the **`traceInputsAndOutputs`** Property to **true** in a **`host.json`** file.  Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-diagnostics?tabs=csharp#functions-20) for additional information

I have set the **traceInputsAndOutputs** in a ***host.json*** file.
[image]

#### Result

**Azure Portal App Insights Log**

[image]
**In local**

[image]